# COM : OUT_OF_PROCESS object's execution context

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, com

While reading about [COM Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-an-object-in-com) I came across this statement about the flag `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`

> If the flags include CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, the class code in the
>   service found under the class's LocalService key is used if this key
>   exists. If no service is specified but an EXE is specified under that
>   same key, the class code associated with that EXE is used. The class
>   code (in either case) will be run in a separate service process on the
>   same computer as the caller.

Does that mean that for following code, the FileDialog object's execution context will be in a separate process ? Is it that simple,i.e. just specify 
`CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` and nothing more is required ? And if thats the case, how can I identify/verify that this separate process is indeed running ?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shobjidl.h> 

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED |
        COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
            IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);

            // Get the file name from the dialog box.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IShellItem *pItem;
                hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    PWSTR pszFilePath;
                    hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                    // Display the file name to the user.
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        MessageBoxW(NULL, pszFilePath,  L"File Path", MB_OK);
                        CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                    }
                    pItem->Release();
                }
            }
            pFileOpen->Release();
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Theoretically, it could work, if FileDialog registry keys specified a valid .exe (or service name). But it's not the case, HKCR\CLSID\{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7} just contains InProcServer32 that points to a dll, so it just works in-process (CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER is ignored in that case). Note that supporting out-of-process COM communications is not a given. It depends how the COM object is written, it must declare proxy/stub (or use Automation types), etc.

Comment: Out-of-process activation of any component that displays embedded UI is not in general possible.  It used to be, back when Microsoft still thought that OLE was useful.  But OLE is quite dead, deservedly so.  Even back then, these shell dialogs were strictly in-process.